# Get file URI in a certain way

Tags: java, file, url, uri

Is there a way to return file:/// through the [File Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). Right now, I have:

```
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
```

The above code returns `file:/<location>` but I want it to return `file:///<location>`. The only way I can think of is `replace("file:/", "file:///")`. Is there a better way?

Comment: `new URI("file:///" + myFile.getAbsolutePath())` Have you tried this?

Comment: @RAnders00 *Never* do that!  The file path may contain characters which are not valid in a URI or URL.

Comment: @fscore The way you're doing it is fine.  That said, `file:` followed by a single slash is a perfectly valid URL (with no authority component), so I'm not sure why you want to change it.

Comment: What is the difference between file:/ and file:///